# PDO MySQL INSERT is removing file extensions before inserting the data into database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

OK. I haven't used stack exchange in a while, so bear with me. I've researched this exhaustively and can't find an answer.

I'm new to PDO statements in general, and am using it for a site I'm working on, which is going to contain an image uploader. Right now, I have this function:

```
function addImage($listing_id, $location) {
    $sql = $this->connection->prepare("INSERT INTO images (listing_id, location) VALUES (?, ?)");
      $sql->execute(array($listing_id, $location));
   }
```

Now, `$location` comes into this function correct - it is an image location, such as `C:\image.png` or `http://test.com/image.jpg`. It is correct at that point. However, upon insertion, the image extensions are being scrubbed, entering only `"C:\image"` or `"http://test.com/image"` into the database, which of course is an issue later when I need to use that information to fetch and or modify the image. I assume it's something to do with a sql injection prevention within PDO? I really don't know. Please help!

Comment: Are you sure that `$location` is as you expect it to be?

Comment: Yes. I echoed it the line before $sql, within the function, and it has the appropriate extension still attached.

Comment: what datatype is the field in the db?

Comment: Well... that was incredibly stupid of me. 
It's a varchar(30). The renaming for the files is putting the addresses for my local test copy at about... 30. Without extensions. Duh. Look at me over-complicating a simple problem?
Thanks.

Comment: no problem, but C:\image.png doesn't fit in 30 spaces?

Comment: nah, that was just an example. The actual images in question are more akin to: C:/uploads/1364940701_0.87007700.jpg or such. At or just over 30 before extension.

Comment: aha, cool! I figured one out!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the Database field must be large enough to accommodate the inputted data. I.E. Varchar(30) must be large enough to hold the path to your pictures. Try Varchar without a limit.